# remote with selected name already exist Android studio , git hub error

Tags: android, github, ide

I'm getting this GitHub error in android studio whenever I'm creating a new repository , And I'm not having any GitHub repo. of the same name.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: open terminal from bottom menu and type `git remote rm github` it should work.

Comment: C:\Users\vraun>git remote rm github
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git terminal is giving me this message !

Answer (score 12):

goto Terminal in android studio and type below command –

```
git remote rm github
```

Comment: Gives an error `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 11):

Open to Android Studio > VCS > Git > Remotes Delete all the addresses that will appear in this section. The problem will solve.

Comment: In 2022.2.1 AS, the `VCS` menu does not have a `Git` selection, so unable to manage remotes this way.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio->Git->Manage Remotes...

And delet all from there with -

Comment: notice in the original question, the screenshot does NOT have a "Git" menu item.  There is only a VCS menu item, which has no `Manage Remotes`.

Answer (score -1):

Tried it.....

Step1. Git-2.11.0-64-bit.exe Setup.

Step2: Git Bash -> git config --global user.name "your userName",
git config --global user.email "your email".

Step3: Android studio->File->Settings->GitHub-> login "your email"

Password "your password" -> test

Step4: VCS->import into version control->share Project.

Step 5: Successful.\

Answer (score -1):

1. Git  $ git remote rename
2. New repository name: eDiot1
       Remote name github1